# Problem converting Image to Base64 in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

So I am trying to convert an image base64 that will be uploaded to SQL Server.

Current code is:

```
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var maxFiles = 1;
    var maxSize = 512000000;
    var format = "image/jpg";
    test = "Something";
    test1 = args.FileCount.ToString();

    foreach (var file in args.GetMultipleFiles(maxFiles))
    {
        var image = await file.RequestImageFileAsync(format, 500, 500);
        test = image.Size.ToString();
        buffer = new byte[image.Size];
        await image.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: maxSize).ReadAsync(buffer);
        test1 = buffer.ToString();
        var imageDataUrl = $"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
        imageDataUrls.Add(imageDataUrl);

        imageString = imageDataUrl;
    }
}
```

It begins fine, however only the top portion of image is actually converted and in the string is followed by thousands of repeating "A". Reconstructing the image just shows the top portion of the image. What am I doing wrong?

Currently I had not uploaded and redownloaded the string, it is all local until I can figure out what is wrong. I am using the `imageString` for the image source. I am using .net 6.0.

Comment: well AAAAAA.... is a stream of 0x00 bytes

Comment: is this all client-side?

Comment: How long is the string? 488mb image would be a huge base64 string

Comment: Your code will work as expected with Blazor wasm, but fail on Blazor server with anything other than small images.  With larger images the data stream will be chopped and you'll see a web socket timeout. There might be a way around this, but then you'll also hit the 64kb data limit on Signal-R. A better solution would be to follow the MS example of how to upload a file with Blazor server. And after the file is uploaded you could then convert it to Base64 for storage in the DB.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server

Comment: *for storage in the DB* - or even, store it in a filesystem..

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Works for me. Files since 1 MB.

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(Stream stream)
{
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Dispose();
    return bytes;
}


private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs args)
{
    string base64String = "";

    try
    {
        var files = args.GetMultipleFiles();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            await using MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
            await file.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1048576).CopyToAsync(fs);
            byte[] somBytes = GetBytes(fs);
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(somBytes, 0, somBytes.Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Imatge 64: " + base64String + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("ERROR: " + e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```